# LNK2019 error when trying to test a dll

Tags: c++, c, linker-errors

I work with an application that appears (just started a few weeks ago, so I am still learning the older apps) to be built in C and my company wants to use that program's ability to make a call to an outside DLL to extend some new functionality. To do this, I started working on my POC, which is the first two files below. The only specification we were given was that the dll has to export the following function:
`extern int __stdcall TestMethod_LoadCustomer(const char * name, char * id);`
I tried to implement that as follows:

TestDLL.h

```
#define TestDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
namespace TestDLL
{
        class TestDLL
        {
        public:
                static TestDLL_API int TestMethod_LoadCustomer(const char* name, char* id);
        };
}
```

TestDLL.cpp

```
// TestDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//  
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestDLL.h"
#include <string.h>

extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall  TestMethod_LoadCustomer(const char* name, char* id)
{
  if (strlen(name) <= 8) {
    strcpy(id, name);           // name contains customer id
  } else {
    id[0] = 0;                  // Customer not found
  }
  return 0;
}
```

These two files compile fine. The problem comes in when I try to test this dll via a separate little console app shown here:
RunTEST.cpp

```
// RunTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "TestDLL.h"

using namespace std;
int _tmain()
{
        char* id= "";
        TestDLL::TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer("77777", id);
        cout << id;
        cin >> id;
        return 0;
}
```

All I am looking for is to be able to pass in a character string into the call TestMethod_LoadCustomer() and have it be added to the id field.

When I actually try to build this solution, I get the following error:

"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl TestDLL::TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer(char const *, char *)" (?TestMethod_LoadCustomer@TestDLL@1@SAHPBDAD@Z) referenced in function _wmain"

I am assuming it has something to do with the way I am trying to reference it in my client app, but I am not sure. I have looked at other LNK2019 errors on StackOverflow, but none of those solutions seemed to work here, of I have incorrectly implemented them. Can any one assist in helping me get rid of this error message?

Comment: Aren't you missing `TestDLL::` before `TestMethod_LoadCustomer` in the TestDLL.cpp?

Comment: **`#define TestDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)`** This should be __declspec(dllimport) for any exe that uses the dll and __declspec(dllexport) for the dll itself.

Comment: @drescherjm, where would that go in the RunTest.cpp file?

Comment: Normally you use a ifdef to define TestDLL_API differently depending on if you are comping the dll or the exe that uses the dll. You can tell this easy by setting a preprocessor definition in the .dll C/C++ settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the TestDLL.cpp file is missing two things:

1) The namespace TestDLL.

2) the TestDLL:: before the method name.

```
// TestDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//  
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestDLL.h"
#include <string.h>

namespace TestDLL {
extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall  TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer(const char* name, char* id)
{
  if (strlen(name) <= 8) {
    strcpy(id, name);           // name contains customer id
  } else {
    id[0] = 0;                  // Customer not found
  }
  return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Making this change actually added a new error ("error C2373: 'TestDLL::TestDLL::TestMethod_LoadCustomer' : redefinition; different type modifiers") along with the LKN2019. Could this be related to drescherjm's comment?

Comment: @cdd the header version is missing the `__stdcall` keyword/modifier, as well as the `extern "C"` statement.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen adding the __stdcall allowed the app to be built, however the extern "C" threw errors of its own.

Comment: I can't imagine you'd be able to use `extern "C"` in the middle of a namespace or class...

Answer (score 0):

While defining the function in TestDLL.cpp you didn't mention that the function is member of the class TestDLL.